# Preview OpenMeetings via Eclipse in development mode

Tags: eclipse, maven, preview, red5, openmeetings

I am using OpenMeetings and want to customize the UI. I have followed the tutorial here - https://openmeetings.apache.org/BuildInstructions.html and got it setup in Eclipse, now I don't know the server the webapps runs on so I setup Tomcat which I did not see in the documentation (I think it's weird).

Please which server does it run on because Tomcat could not return the pages when I ran the webapp on it. I did further inquiry and got to know it uses red5 server, my concern now is that how do I run it from Eclipse so as to be able to preview the pages and see the changes I have made?

Answer (score 1):

Apache OpenMeetings is build on top on Red5 server, which is based on Tomcat.
It is impossible to run OpenmMeetings on Tomcat.

You need to start Red5 server bundled into distribution